# Apply additional filter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
xml = xml + '<states>';
xml = xml + '<state name="KS"> ';
xml = xml + '  <city>Overland Park</city>';
xml = xml + '  <city>Mission</city>';
xml = xml + '  <city>Topeka</city>';
xml = xml + '</state>';
xml = xml + '<state name="MO">';
xml = xml + '<city>Kansas City</city>';
xml = xml + '<city>Belton</city>';
xml = xml + '<city>Clayton</city>';
xml = xml + '</state>';
xml = xml + '</states>';

alert(xml);

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

$xml = $(xmlDoc);

$(xml).find('state[name="MO"]').each(function() {
  var whichState = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(whichState);
  $('city', this).each(function() {
    whichCity = $(this).text();
    console.log("City: " + whichCity);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to filter the XML by state and city.  Is there a way to apply an additional filter to this statement:  `$('city', this).each(function(){`. ?

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean with "add an additional filter"? couldn't you just create a function that takes the state and the city as arguments and just filter the results adequately?

Comment: I was just looking for a simple elegant jQuery solution.  I can easily write an if else statement and be done with it.

Comment: checkout this blog post https://forum.jquery.com/topic/selecting-xml-node-by-value-text